# Where can I find learning material on how to play the Alekhine-Chatard Gambit Declined?

Tags: opening, gambits, french-defense

[image: Alekhine-Chatard Gambit Declined with 6..h6]

I'm looking for materials on how to play the Alekhine-Chatard Gambit Declined. Which books and references are available for this variation? I'm looking for possible good moves to play for when this  gambit is declined.

Comment: Do you mean specifically the line with 6...h6, or also 6...c5, 6...a6 or 6...b6 ?

Comment: I mean all possible good moves against this variation, which gambit is not accepted.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest a game I recently played over the board to equality?  Both my opponent and I are 1680-ish FIDE-rated.  I don't know the theory of this line yet, so moves were found over the board.

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. e5 Nfd7 6. h4 a6 {I went into a long think here, but a6 is necessary to prevent the knight from entering from the flank, if Black plays an early c5 now} 7. Bxe7 Qxe7 8. Qg4 f5 9. Qg3 c5 10. Nf3 Nc6 11. O-O-O cxd4 12. Nxd4 Nxd4 13. Rxd4 Nc5 14. Bd3 Nxd3+ 15. Qxd3 O-O 16. Qe2 Bd7 17. g4 Rac8 18. gxf5 Rxf5 19. Rg1 Bb5 20. Nxb5 axb5 21. Rdg4 Rf7 22. Qxb5 Qc7 23. Qe2 Qc5 24. f4 g6 {Rxf4 now is tempting, but Black would get checkmated via Rxg7+ Kh8 Rxh7+ Kxh7 Qh5#} 25. h5 Rxf4 26. hxg6 h6 27. R4g2 Kg7 28. Rh1 Re4 29. Qd2 Qe3 1/2-1/2
```

And Chess History page has this http://www.chesshistory.com/winter/extra/french.html

Comment: Black would be much better after 19...Be8.